# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large. WCF

Tags: wcf

I am calling a WCF service and I am trying to an upload an image. However, when it reaches the WCF service it has this error:

**The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.**

The tracing on the WCF service says:

**System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

So, heaving read that, easy peasy I thought. Just change that setting and away we go. However, not so. I have edited the binding via the "Edit WCF Settings" GUI in Visual Studio. It has modified the web.confg as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="debugMode" name="Portal.Service" />
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="debugMode">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Portal" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

However the error still occurs? The issue is definitely with the WCF service as I see the exception in the service trace logs. The calling client (ASP.Net) refers to it as the "remote server".

I also have these settings on the client web.config:

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Portal"  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

In IIS I have set the **uploadReadAhead** size too. I'm at a loss on what to do now. The bindings match, the settings were changed via GUI. What more could it want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You changed the configuration for the binding, but I don't see anywhere in your service's configuration file where you actually *use* the binding ("BasicHttpBinding_Portal").

You can do one of two things.  Either assign that binding to an explicit endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute of the `<service>` tag, or make the configuration you set up as the default for `basicHttpBinding` by omitting the `name` attribute on the `<binding>` tag.  Since you don't have an explicit endpoint defined, I'd recommend the second approach:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"  />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The key point here is that you must tell the service to use the binding you've specified.  If you don't, the default values for the binding will be used.  By omitting the `name` attribute on the binding configuration, you're telling the framework to use that configuration for any `basicHttpBinding` requests.